# How to parse text too variable for formal grammars but too constrained for NLP?

Tags: parsing, nlp, linguistics

I'm dealing with a corpus of text that is written informally, but generally conforms to a very standard format by convention (think something like *Froyo Frozen Yogurt*, *Smucker's Peanut Butter*) and occasionally requires recursion (*Froyo Frozen Yogurt with Smucker's Peanut Butter*).

With regexes, the complexity quickly grows out of hand (*Frozen Yogurt by Froyo*, *Froyo Frozen Yogurt with Peanut Butter by Smucker's*, etc).

I'm having trouble finding resources to help me write an EBNF for this, and NLP method are too complex (plus my "parts of speech" don't really correspond to normal english). Is there an intermediate approach, aimed at semi-formalized text?

Comment: a coule of other examples of such lexicons might be the naming rules for warez releases: http://scenerules.irc.gs/t.html?id=2009_MP3.nfo and european nobility titles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_and_noble_ranks

Comment: I think we need to see more examples of what is valid and what is not.

Comment: Some reasonable templates: [Manufacturer] [Flavor] [Food Type], [Flavor] [Food Type] (made|prepared|sold) by [Manufacturer] -- we have a complete(ish) lexicon of Food Type and possibly Manufacturer. Contrived example: *Edy's Chocolate Chip Ice Cream with Praline made by Nestle and Nabisco* (parse tree is something like this: http://www.asciiflow.com/#6223280195879178536)

Comment: Invalid: *Smucker's Racecar* (unknown Food Type), *Yogurt imported by Froyo* ('imported by' not a known relationship), *Reebok Ice Cream* (Reebok known not to be a food manufacturer). These could appear in freeform sentences (*I like Smucker's Peanut Butter*) but it's more important to solve the standalone case

Comment: Maybe you could get a good answer for this on [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Good call, reposted here: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/how-to-parse-text-too-variable-for-formal-grammars-but-too-constrained-for-nlp

Comment: I am not sure what your question is.. what is the task you are trying to do? Can you provide some sample input/output in the body of the question that illustrates what you are trying to do and why it is a tricky problem. Are you trying to identify names of products in text, or trying to parse strings containing full names of products and identify the different components of that name?

Comment: @adi92 I am trying to do the following: 1) verify that strings describe products of interest (e.g. *edy's ice cream* but not *Reebok Ice Cream*) 2) extract manufacturers and their relationship to each product or part of product 3) possibly do this in freeform or malformed text. The tricky part for doing this with regex is possible recursive sub-patterns (sometimes 3 levels!) and high number of variations in phrasing/order.

Comment: Still confused.. Do you already know which companies make which products (i.e. reebook does not make ice cream, etc) or are you trying to extract that information from some dataset.. If you don't have that information beforehand, how can you make judgements about a particular product name being invalid? If Reebok actually started to make Ice Cream and you found a bunch of mentions of that in your data, how is your system meant to validate or invalidate this?

Answer (score 0):

You could build a cheap and simple EBNF "into" your favorite programming language, e.g: (pseudocode, let's imagine these variables represent regexes)

```
var digit_excluding_zero = "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9";
var digit = "0|" + digit excluding zero;
```

(this is the first example from the [EBNF Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form#Basics))